# LESS restricting CSS-files to certain viewports (Shopware)

Tags: css, less, shopware

I ran into a problem at working with Shopware today. I want to restrict the usage of certain CSS files (mobile css and desktop css).

Problem is: both files are being used and it seems to not letting me restrict the files to the viewports. What did I do wrong?

Would be great if you could help me out here, since Ive just started in LESS templating. Cheers!

```
{extends file='parent:frontend/index/header.tpl'}

@phoneLandscapeViewportWidth: 30em;     
@tabletViewportWidth: 48em;             
@tabletLandscapeViewportWidth: 64em;    
@desktopViewportWidth: 78.75em;


when (@media screen and (min-width: @tabletLandscapeViewportWidth)=true) {
{block name="frontend_index_header_css_screen" append}
    <link type="text/css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" href="{link file='frontend/_public/src/css/custom.css'}" />
{/block}
}

@media screen and (max-width: @tabletLandscapeViewportWidth) {
{block name="frontend_index_header_css_screen" append}
    <link type="text/css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" href="{link file='frontend/_public/src/css/mobile.css'}" />
{/block}
}
```

Comment: You need to put that in the LESS files themselves.

Comment: To expand on the previous comment: you can't include HTML (a <link> element) inside CSS (a @media query).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, the code you see is actually from the header.tpl I extended for my template

Comment: @Trantarx: That doesn't change anything; you can't write LESS code outside a LESS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: As the comments already state out, you're mixing up different languages.

By now - from your example - you're dealing with three things, that cannot be combined in that way as you try it:

1. **LESS**: This is a preprocessor language that - at least in a Shopware 5 context is meant to be compiled and *generates* your CSS
   files (there is a way of including LESS files directly, but this is not recommended for production, so I'd leave this part out).
2. **CSS**: Your stylesheets that are rendered. If you statically include them into your template (I mean if you're not using Javascript to dynamically change your DOM) you WILL have to decide whether you use one or another CSS-File *before* you render the DOM.
   This brings us to the next CSS related-topic:

   1. ***Media Queries:*** The concept of media queries is not meant to dynamically change the DOM (i.e. clearing out one CSS-Stylesheet and bringing in another).
      Imagine the following case: You sit at your Desktop-PC and slowly drag the window of your browser smaller and smaller until your viewport-width is smaller than 64em (@tabletLandscapeViewportWidth). What is the media-query supposed to do? Request the server to load another resource?
      Remember: Media Queries are CSS and CSS is all about style of your Website. In a normal case it is served once when the page loads and the rest of the magic happens in your client. There is no further communication with the server (and this is what you'd try to do, i guess).
3. **Smarty (.tpl)**: The third part you mix up here is the .tpl files, and these come from the Smarty-Template-Engine. So we have to be clear here: Smarty *renders* your template. This happens server-side *before* the page is delivered to the requesting client.
   That means you can decide to load one or the other css at this point (but not by media-queries, I'll come back to that later) but once the page is delivered to the client, Smarty's work is over and it will do nothing without another server-request (i.e. by an AJAX-call).

I must confess that I am not absolutely understanding what exactly you want to achieve. If you only some CSS definitions to a certian viewport width, you don't need to go into the template at all.

Let's assume you only want your styles that are in the `custom.css` apply when the viewport is larger than `@tabletViewportWidth` and everything below should serve `mobile.css`.

Since you can nest media-queries in CSS3 it shouldn't be a problem to wrap the whole less file into a media-query like that:

```
@media screen and (min-width: @tabletLandscapeViewportWidth) {
   // all your custom.css content
}

@media screen and (max-width: @tabletLandscapeViewportWidth) {
   // all your mobile.css content
}
```

But please keep in mind that this excludes all other media-types, so you maybe should go with `@media all`.

If you really want to change the stylesheets dynamically you should go with a library like [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) and make an AJAX-Request that dynamically changes the stylesheet, but imho this is kind of an ugly solution that only makes (no real, but with a bit of fantasy a little bit) sense if *no* stylesheet is loaded (or a base-stylesheet with styles, that both .css-files share) and the call is made to request a smaller CSS-File.
But if the production-css-file is minified this shouldn't be worth the effort.

As you can see, in the offered solution we are not even touching a smarty-tpl-file. But i want to mention a little thing if you work with smarty:
You're extending a file here, therefore every junk of code needs to be *inside* of the `{block}`-tags you're extending. Smarty doesn't know where to put the code otherwise and will throw an error (even though, as explained LESS-Code won't work anyways here ;) ).

regards

Comment: Thank you very much! Made things clear! Also great explanation! Thanks!